# I want to check and uncheck the check box of my form using PHP script

Tags: php

Hi Guys i want to check and uncheck the check box of my form using PHP script.
in database i am using datatype TinyInt for storing either 0 or 1.
I am using following code.

```
<tr>
    <td><div id="formEditProfileLblAEmail">Allow Email</div> 
    </td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="<?php

$sql = "Select firstname,middlename,lastname,nickname,require_email,allow_scores from user_info where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 


          if($count>0)
          {

             if($row['require_email']=='1')
              {
                 echo 'checked';
              }
              else
              {
                 echo 'unchecked';
              }
          }
          else
              echo 'unchecked';

          ?>" name="formEditProfileChkAEmail"  id="formEditProfileChkAEmail" /> </td></tr>
```

But My Check box is always coming checked whether i am having 0 or 1 in database.

Comment: This is definitely open to SQL injection.  Can someone familiar with PHP's prepared statement functionality advise on how to avoid this?

Comment: problem is not of SQL Injection i can prevent that ,basically i want to check/uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: it is not PHP question, it's HTML question. Learn HTML.

Comment: This got nothing to do with JavaScript as you're setting the checkbox state with the server side PHP code - removed the tag.

Comment: i really dont want to do with javascript in this scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not do with else part of if just add inside if

Remove the `checked="` which is outside the if

```
<input type="checkbox" 
<?php if($row['require_email']=='1')  {
                 echo 'checked="checked"';
 }
```

Nothing to do with checkboxes which you want them to be unchecked.

Comment: done Man Thanks .will mark it answered after 5 remaining minutes.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked), the `checked` attribute is boolean.  That is, if you don't set it to a value that implies false, the user agent will *probably* decide that it is true, i.e. checked.  Historically the mere *presence* of this attribute indicated that the box should be checked, hence why this is the likely default value.

You can test this by looking at the source - I suspect you'll have your page rendered with `checked="unchecked"`, which will still render the box as checked.

<s>You can fix this by changing "unchecked" to "false" in your PHP source, in order to get the correct boolean behaviour you're looking for.</s>

Edit: the specs further go on to define that [boolean attributes can only take one legal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) (which implies `true`) - so to produce correct HTML with this attribute set to `false`, the only way to do this is to omit the attribute altogether.  [Shakti Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723561/hi-guys-i-want-to-check-and-uncheck-the-check-box-of-my-form-using-php-script/4723596#4723596) describes how to achieve this (and gets a +1 from me).

Answer (score 1):

There is no value such as "unchecked" for the [checked property](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp), so you need to echo:

```
checked="checked"
```

if the value is > 0 and nothing at all if it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is the text being printed at all? Try `checked="checked"`.